# Is there a way to put a dynamic framework into another framework in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, swift5

In my experiments, I build without problems, but no matter what I do, I need to add both frameworks to the client project. So is there any way to make it into Single framework?
So I dont want add the subframework, I want to add only the last framework that I created in client project.

I added sub-framework inside the main framework , it builds ok.
[image]

In my client project;
[image]

And;
[image]

But inside client project,it says "missing required module "MySubframework".
It is finding it in my own computer because I compile it, but when I send main framework another place it says that.